# SwiftUI: unexpected behavior with two List side by side and a NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a screen with two `List` side by side, inside a `NavigationView`. The layout is rendered correctly, and I can independently scroll both lists. The problem is that, when I scroll the first list, it goes behind the navigation bar without triggering the effect of applying a background color to it. Here's a gif showing what's going on:

[image]

And this is the code I'm using for this view:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                List {
                    Section(header: Text("Header left")) {
                        ForEach(0..<600) { integer in
                            Text("\(integer)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)

                List {
                    Section(header: Text("Header right")) {
                        ForEach(0..<400) { integer in
                            Text("\(integer)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Example")
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }

}
```

Would this be a SwiftUI bug? If not, how can I make the first list correctly interact with the navigation bar when scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. The way the `NavigationView` and `NavigationStack` work, they only consider the last occurring `List` or `ScrollView` in its content to animate the navigation bar.

The only workarounds I can think of now are to:

1. Hide the navigation bar with
   `.navigationBarHidden(true)`
   or
   `.toolbar(.hidden)` (for iOS 16+) modifiers
2. Fix the navigation bar in place

```
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
.toolbarBackground(Color.white, for: .navigationBar)
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
```

for iOS 16+ or the UIKit-ish way for older iOS versions by playing with `UINavigationBarAppearance`

3. Implement your own navigation bar, track the lists with geometry readers, and do the animation based on the list positions but the effort here will not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with disabling `UINavigationBar`'s large title and transparency.

```
import Introspect

@State private var navigationBar: UINavigationBar?

HStack(spacing: 0) {
    ...
}
.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
.introspectNavigationController {
    $0.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = $0.navigationBar.standardAppearance
    navigationBar = $0.navigationBar
}
.onDisappear {
    navigationBar?.scrollEdgeAppearance = nil
    navigationBar = nil
}
```

To access `UINavigationController` I used [SwiftUI Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) lib