# NavigationView is not collapsing while having 2 List/ScrollView in HStack - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to show 2 List side by side, by wrapping up both the Lists in HStack with SwiftUI framework.

BUT NavigationView is not collapsing while left side of List will scroll.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                List(0..<21) { _ in
                    Text("Hello, world!").padding()
                }
                
                List(0..<21) { _ in
                    Text("Hello, world!").padding()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            //Added just to see navigation bar items
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button("Edit") {}, trailing: Button("Done") {})
        }
    }
}
```

How can I collapse NavigationView while scrolling left List?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up with disabling `UINavigationBar`'s large title and transparency.

Check code in this answer: [SwiftUI: unexpected behavior with two List side by side and a NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849509/swiftui-unexpected-behavior-with-two-list-side-by-side-and-a-navigationview/74395831#74395831)

Answer (score 0):

This solution may not answer your question directly but if you are okay with showing the title in a different style, give this modifier a try:

`.navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"), displayMode: .inline)`

Comment: first, I want to keep Navigation Bar as automatic and second, inline also not resolve this issue. btw thanks for the suggetion.